# Use different font for SyndicationFeed title than summary in richtextbox - C#

Tags: c#, .net

I am making an RSS Reader in C#. It gets the feed and adds it to a rich text box. Is there a way to have the title in a feed be a separate font than the summary in the rich text box? If so, how? Here is my code:

```
if (feedsList.SelectedItem != null)
{
     feedTxt.Text = "";
     string url = feedsList.GetItemText(feedsList.SelectedItem);
     Uri myUri = new Uri(url, UriKind.Absolute);
     XmlReader reader = XmlReader.Create(url);
     SyndicationFeed feed = SyndicationFeed.Load(reader);
     foreach (SyndicationItem item in feed.Items)
     {
          feedTxt.Text = feedTxt.Text + item.Title.Text;
          feedTxt.Text = feedTxt.Text + "\n\n" + item.Summary.Text + "\n\n";
     }
}
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `Selection` property of on `RichTextBox` control. Something Like this:

```
if (feedsList.SelectedItem != null)
{
    feedTxt.Text = "";
    string url = feedsList.GetItemText(feedsList.SelectedItem);
    Uri myUri = new Uri(url, UriKind.Absolute);
    XmlReader reader = XmlReader.Create(url);
    SyndicationFeed feed = SyndicationFeed.Load(reader);

    foreach (SyndicationItem item in feed.Items)
    {
        // Store current content length of RichTextBox
        int currentLength = feedTxt.Length;

        // Append new content
        feedTxt.Text += item.Title.Text + "\n\n";
        feedTxt.Text += item.Summary.Text + "\n\n";

        // Set the font for Title using selection
        feedTxt.SelectionStart = currentLength.Length;
        feedTxt.SelectionLength = item.Title.Text.Length;
        feedTxt.SelectionFont = new System.Drawing.Font("Tahoma", 24);

        // Set the font for Summary using selection
        feedTxt.SelectionStart = currentLength + item.Title.Text.Length;
        feedTxt.SelectionLength = item.Summary.Text;
        feedTxt.SelectionFont = new System.Drawing.Font("Arial", 16);

        // Reset Selection
        txtTest.SelectionStart = 0;
        txtTest.SelectionLength = 0;
    }
}
```

## Update

Looks like you can't append new content and style at the same time (possible limitation of Winforms?). My simple solution is to append all the content in one sweep and calculate all the selections you want to style and push them to a List.

Then you do a second pass looping through all your selections and do the styling.

You need this struct first:

```
  struct ArticleSelection
  {
      public int TitleStart { get; set; }
      public int TitleEnd { get; set; }
      public int SummaryStart { get; set; }
      public int SummaryEnd { get; set; }
  };
```

**Updated Code**

```
if (feedsList.SelectedItem != null)
{
    feedTxt.Text = "";
    string url = feedsList.GetItemText(feedsList.SelectedItem);
    Uri myUri = new Uri(url, UriKind.Absolute);
    XmlReader reader = XmlReader.Create(url);
    SyndicationFeed feed = SyndicationFeed.Load(reader);


    // Create List to store our selections
    List<ArticleSelection> articleSelections = new List<ArticleSelection>();

    // Loop all incoming content
    foreach (SyndicationItem item in feed.Items)
    {
        // Store current content length of RichTextBox
        int currentLength = feedTxt.Length;

        // Append new content
        feedTxt.Text += item.Title.Text + "\n\n";
        feedTxt.Text += item.Summary.Text + "\n\n";

        // Calculate selection
        articleSelections.Add(new ArticleSelection()
        {
            TitleStart = currentLength,
            TitleEnd = feed.Item1.Length,
            SummaryStart = currentLength + feed.Item1.Length,
            SummaryEnd = feedTxt.Text - currentLength // This accounts for new lines above
        }); ; 
    }


    // Loop through the content and style it
    foreach (ArticleSelection selection in articleSelections)
    { 
        // Set the selection for Title
        txtTest.SelectionStart = selection.TitleStart;
        txtTest.SelectionLength = selection.TitleEnd;
        txtTest.SelectionFont = new Font("Tahoma", 24);

        // Set the selection for Summary
        txtTest.SelectionStart = selection.SummaryStart;
        txtTest.SelectionLength = selection.SummaryEnd;
        txtTest.SelectionFont = new Font("Arial", 14);
    }

    // Remove Selection
    txtTest.DeselectAll();
}
```

You should get something like this:
[image: Example code output]

Comment: Thanks! This is really helpful! The only problem is that it only works with one item in a feed. Is there a way it could work with multiple items?

Comment: @UnknownGobo Did you use the latest code? I edited to work in loop.

Comment: I used the latest code. Here is a screenshot of the program: https://drive.google.com/open?id=1Rm1MvndoDdaTCEErlzDqwPk-nqmSl0rm

Comment: @UnknownGobo The image is not publically visible

Comment: Sorry, I needed to reload Google Drive to get it to work. My bad. https://drive.google.com/file/d/1Rm1MvndoDdaTCEErlzDqwPk-nqmSl0rm/view?usp=sharing

Comment: I have tried multiple feeds and the issue seems to persist.

Comment: This works! Thank you so much for the help! I plan on releasing this program so I'll credit you for your contributions.

Comment: Awesome, I’d recommend extending it to make it more reusable!

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/198849/discussion-between-unknown-gobo-and-riddell).